# In what case that application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: been called?

Tags: ios, background, voip

My app is for Voip,and it can run in background. When it runs for a long time in background, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:' method is called and then my app stop running.I want to know :Whey a voip app run in background ,the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method been called? And if this method been called,what should i do to make my app keep running? Can any body help?Thank you...

Comment: plz show the crash log..

Comment: I am sorry,there is no crash log,when application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method recalled, other UIApplicationDelegate method is not been called,it's so strange...

Comment: Is it the simulator u r seeing no crash log? its difficult to figure out without a crash log..

Comment: if u have a device, go to xcode->organizer->Devices->(left column)Device name->Device Logs = Crash Logs

Comment: i am so sorry, there really no crash log...do you have any other ideas to help me?thank you

Comment: nope, most likely its a memory leak(big)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing but I think that your application may  receiving memory warnings. And `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` called only once for each run of the application . Just try to investigate by overriding `- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application` method in your app delegate . That may be the reason of the crashing.

Answer (score 0):

VoIP apps start when the phone starts. You'll see your app launching in the phone console at startup. If you use log calls to application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, more than once, your app is probably crashing or the phone is killing it for the memory. If you are registered as a voip app in your plist, you can call setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: in applicationDidEnterBackground to run a SIP register every 10 min (600s). BTW, don't try to keep application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions running; I believe it gets 5s before iOS kills your app.

Look at Tips for Developing a VoIP app: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html